# parse html elements using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, google-chrome-devtools

I want to retrieve value of "data-default-src" from html below. Seems like the body is in shadow-root node or hidden in the source code. This is seen only through chrome's inspect element feature not when done ctrl+u.

```
<body onload="handleOnLoad();" style="margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;height:100%;
position:relative;overflow:hidden" id="myPlayer" 
data-default-src="https://cdn.video.playwire.com/12272/videos/4483914/video-sd.mp4?hosting_id=12272">
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Elements media = doc.select("body");

            for (Element links: media) 
            {
            System.out.println((links.attr("abs:data-default-src")));
            }
```

and this too:

```
Element body = doc.body();
System.out.println(body.attr("data-default-src"));
```

Comment: "This is seen only through chrome's inspect element feature not when done ctrl+u." This means that the attribute was generated dynamically in the browser, most likely using JavaScript. JSoup is an HTML library, not a full browser emulator. You will need to figure out another way to get the value.

Comment: @still_learning Thanks. Any other extracting API that you know of could help resolve?

Comment: This depends on your requirements and how the attribute is generated. Have a look at [this page](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/3694955). I tried a few some time ago, HTMLUnit seems to be a robust choice.

Comment: Yes, I will go through the API. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which is a library that provides a headless browser. With this you could load the page up as if you were really accessing it, causing all the javascript to be evaluated and any dynamic content to be inserted into the DOM. There you can choose to use HTMLUnit's DOM API or throw it into JSoup.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out.